# Host www.xyz.in not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku

I have a domain purchased from name.com - I am using heroku for hosting a rails app for this domain. Today I tried to setup DNS for this domain.
The top level domain works fine but when I try to setup CNAME for "www", I get the following error :

```
ubuntu:~/rails_projects/socal$ host www.xyz.in
Host www.xyz.in not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
('xyz' is just for example)
```

My CNAME settings in name.com looks like :

```
Record Type     Record Host     Record Answer          TTL  
CNAME           www.xyz.in      proxy.heroku.com       1800
```

This is as per the instructions on heroku.com-http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-
domains
Not sure what could be wrong with my DNS settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest using a A record for www ,as a Cname will cause 2 lookups at the server doubling the load. Cnames were designed fir when you don't control the other domain, An A record is much more suited for this

Comment: I cant create www A record with proxy.heroku.com - I get 'Invalid character used for record answer' I will try creating with ip

Comment: Created A record for all heroku ips - still same error :  www.socl.in  174.129.212.2
www.socl.in  75.101.145.87
www.socl.in  75.101.163.44

Comment: any time lag before the changes are reflected ?

Comment: If you setup another record it should ask the server as it hasn't cached it yet.

Comment: does heroku assign you a IP or a hostname?

Comment: Heroku suggests 'proxy.heroku.com' for creating CNAME for www - and gives 3 ips to create A record for top level domain. I tried using hostname 'proxy.heroku.com' it throws error - invalid character used for record answer

Comment: Sorry a Cname is correct in this situation what you need to do is check to see if you set your domains in heroku ssh like in the instructions. Your DNS record is www.mydomain.com. Cname proxy.herkou.com

Comment: Holy ! - I did not put a "." after 'proxy.heroku.com'

Comment: still same error though !

Comment: can we get the name to test?

Comment: which name do want

Comment: Your domainname

Comment: www.socl.in - where will you try ?

Comment: its workign now...

Answer (score 3):

[I suggest reading this article that explain why it's so important to avoid an `A record` on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords).